# eDiscovery PST Export Tool

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I have a user in in-place eDiscovery and hold in O365.  I'm trying to export an entry to PST, it runs everything until it gets to one point where it gives me the following error.

Export failed with error: Export failed with error type: 'FailedToAutoDiscoverExchangeWebServiceUrl'.

Can someone please help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you contact Office365 support?

Comment: Trying to, we have a vendor that we work through and it's difficult getting a hold of them?

Comment: You can try to call support directly 877-913-2707 and log ticket.

Comment: When you go to ADMIN portal in Office365 and navigate to the DOMAINS section, could you please confirm all the records setup correctly?

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot AutoDiscover errors with O365 I recommend you start with the connectivity Analyzer.
https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/

Go to the O365 tab and run the Outlook autodiscover tests.  If checks all methods of discovery so you will have some fails -  but overall you want the task to complete.  If it fails expand all the results and scroll to the bottom to see what the message is.

You either don't have auto-discover configured correctly for your domain, or you may have a Hybrid configuration and your on-prem servers are not returning the correct results.